# How to find adjacent lines?

Tags: qgis, line, splitting

I managed to split all my line features (streets) with "Split lines with lines" tool. This tool splits lines at every intersection. I would like to add the information to the attribute table that which lines (streets) straddle lines. I would like to add this information to each and every line, so not doing it manually would be amazing. Maybe it was not the plainest way of explaining what I would like so I attach an image that might makes it easier to understand:

[image]

Is this possibe at all?

Comment: just to clarify what you mean.. in the case of Main Street, you'd want to find East Street and Devonshire Street which both branch off it?

Comment: Main Street has three parts as it was split by the intersections of Emerald St, Devonshire St, East St and Victoria St. As you said, I would like to find out which streets "cut" Main St, not only the middle of it but all parts. So southwestern part was cut by Emerald St and Devonshire St, the middle part was cut by Devonshire St and East St, and northeastern part was cut by East St and Victoria St. I would like to add these information to the proper row of the attr.table. Moreover, all my streets were cut by other streets so I would like to find out which streets cut which in every case.